# How can I set correct timezone for a date field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm using **moment** for generating time and date:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const emailModel = require('./api/models/emails');

sentTime=moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format();
console.log(sentTime);    //console log  shows correct time
emailModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: emailInfo._id }, {sentTime: sentTime }, { upsert: true },function (err, doc) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
});
```

And this is Schema that I'm using **mongoose** :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EmailSchema = new Schema({
   .
   .
   .
    sentTime: {
        type: Date,
        trim: true
    }
   .
   .
   .
});
```

Problem is:
Console log shows correct time *2020-01-07T12:23:00-08:00*  BUT mongoose saved incorrect timezone in DB : *2020-01-07T20:23:01.000+00:00*

Comment: It's because string is getting converted into Date which is usually in UTC format. What is the specific reason for opting region `America/Los_Angeles` ? If it's your local time & wanted to insert the local time, there is a work around but if you want region specific let's say one request has  `America/Los_Angeles` the other has  `America/Chicago` then it might be a bit difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the default behavior of Mongodb is to: ([From the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/))

> MongoDB stores times in UTC by default, and will convert any local
>   time representations into this form.

As a solution (and rightly so) what they recommend is:

> Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time
>   value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute
>   the original local time in their application logic.

**Update:**
Since you are already using `moment-timezone` a simple way I would go about this is:

Change the `EmailSchema` to have a timezone field and create a [Mongoose virtual field](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) on that schema to get adjusted time.

```
const schemaOpts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };
const EmailSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sentTime: {
      type: Date,
      trim: true
    },
    timeZone: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  schemaOpts
);

EmailSchema.virtual("adjustedTime").get(function() {
  return moment.tz(this.sentTime, this.timeZone).format();
});

//fetching data
const result = await EmailSchema.findOne({}).exec();
console.info("result::", result.toJSON());

//note that if using .lean() for performance which has a caveat on using .toJSON()
```

Answer (score 0):

trick for this case is before save, you need to add time with date. Ex: 2021/01/02 ==> 2021/01/02 15:00:00, ofcouse hour is always equal or greater than 04:00:00. Becase without time, date will be 00:00:00 and mongo will convert it to default timezone and substract hour with 4.